# Generating PFX from CSR

Tags: c#, certificate, pfx, csr, certificate-authority

I have created Certificate Signing Request (CSR) now i have to send it to Certificate Authority (CA) so that it can sign it and return me a .PFX certificate. I don't want to use makecert.exe or openssl.exe. Also certificate should not be self signed and i have to do this thing programmatically in c#.

I am also not sure if CA will create PFX or it will only sign PFX. In simple words I can say that I need to generate .PFX certificate from this CSR that is not self signed but is signed by CA using C#.Net.

I got CSR creation code from [this link](http://perfectresolution.com/?p=499).

Comment: Where is your CA located? If within the same network, then the existing windows calls in IEnroll(4, i think, please check) will help. If your CA is present in a different physical location, then you will be required to understand how the CA is allowing you to interface with it. Ask for the CA's certificate policy statement.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot generate a PFX file from a CSR as to generate a PFX file you will need the private key.But a CSR can be signed by the CA.

Once it is signed PFX file can be exported with the key and the signed certificate.

They are different ways you can do this based on howthe CSR was generated(i.e. IIS or open ssl etc.)

Comment: I am generating CSR using certreq.exe and then sending it company for getting it signed by CA, After i have the CER file but PFX option is showing disabled when i am exporting. Here is the full link of the question,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76495397/export-private-key-is-not-showing-when-creating-certificate-from-csr?noredirect=1#comment134895970_76495397