# Export private key is not showing when creating certificate from CSR

Tags: powershell, private-key, pfx, csr, pkcs#12

I am trying to create CSR from powershell script. When running the script CSR is getting generated. After that certificate is created.
Now when executing certmgr on my window machine i am opening Certificate Export Wizard.
When clicking Next option of "Export private Key" is not showing up.

If i create a CSR through run -> mmc then the option of exporting private key is showing up.

I am opening the PowerShell as an admin only.

**sampleCreateCSR.ini**

```
[Version]
Signature= '$Windows NT$'
[NewRequest]
Subject = "CN=dummy, OU=IS, O=Sample, L=Bangalore, S=Karnataka, C=IN"
FriendlyName = dummy
KeyLength = 2048
Exportable = TRUE
MachineKeySet = TRUE
SMIME = False
PrivateKeyArchive = FALSE
UserProtected = FALSE
UseExistingKeySet = FALSE
ProviderName = Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider
ProviderType = 12
HashAlgorithm = sha256
RequestType = PKCS10
KeyUsage = 0xa0
[EnhancedKeyUsageExtension]
OID=1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
```

Then opening Powershell as admin.
certreq.exe -new .\sampleCreateCSR.ini CSRsample.txt

Successfully, a CSR is created, and after that, we generate a certificate.
Will install that certificate in personal folder in certificates.

Next step I type run -> certmgr.msc -> click on personal -> certificate -> select the certificate and click export.

Certificate export wizard will open. When click next we see "Export private Key" option but when generating through Powershell the screen is not there.

[image: I get next screen in which this option is disable.]

Comment: There is more than one type of certificate.  Looks like the certificate is a CER, not a PFX,

Comment: the same logic is working when I am generating it through Microsoft management console on my local. Through Powershell it's not working.
I am assuming it's some access which is required in the powershell script or need to add something in script to enable private key export while generating CSR but i may be wrong.

Comment: The key may not be the same parameters that are in your ini file.  There may be more than one key in the certificate.  The certificate may be encrypted.  The may not be a signature on older keys.

Comment: i am creating CSR first then through certmgr will create Certificate but key option is not showing in certmgr with CSR used when generating certificate.
Issue is definately in CSR creation through script but i am not able to pinpoint as to what.

Comment: Sha256 does not have a private key.  The INI parameters also say private key = false.  Some encryption algorithms have both a private and public key.  Sha256 has only one key and the key length 256 bits.  You have key length 2048.  See : https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/cyber-security-tutorial/sha-256-algorithm